# MySQL: which table will be returned on 2nd Left join

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.column_name3 = table3.column_name3
```

based on the explanation online it says

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table
>   (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The
>   result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

how about on `LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.column_name3 = table3.column_name3` does it return `table1` or `table2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the previous join joined with the third one.

Try to think of tables put side by side and align rows where the join condition is true! That's the final result.

Let's try a simple example to make it more clear.

You have 3 tables: `People`, `Cities`, `States`.

You want to display, for each person in the db, the city and the state where he lives.

Table structure would be something like this:

`People`: id_person, name, id_city

`Cities`: id_city, city, id_state

`States`: id_state, state

The final query would be something like this:

```
select p.name, c.city, s.state 
from people p
inner join cities c on p.id_city = c.id_city
inner join states s on c.id_state = s.id_state
```

and the result would be all the column side by side, like so:

```
name    city    state
----    ----    -----
Simon   Berlin  Germany
Mattia  Rome    Italy
Francis Paris   France
```

If we execute the first join, we get the information of the first 2 tables together, so name of the person and name of the city. Then with the third join, you get the previous 2 joined tables with the third one